# modeling clothes

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine, cloth-simulation

I have no idea how to ask this, mostly because I have no idea whats going on. So I'm going to try my best to phrase this question. Pictures will be added for a better understanding of what im talking about.
So I am modeling a shirt for my characcter generated using the manuel bastioni software, but everytime i fit the shirt and change the models pose, the shirt does not follow.  What am i doing wrong??[image]

Comment: Try applying scale, ctrl + A then click "Scale" on your shirt

Comment: I did that, it did not have the desired effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read through http://www.manuelbastioni.com/guide_a_detailed_tutorial_about_clothes.php fully? This should explain the process to fit to mesh, however it doesn't seem to actually add an armature modifier to stay with the pose, you need to manually update, which makes it useless for animation. Each time you repose you need to hit the fit button again.

If you need animation, you need to check that your clothes have an armature modifier with the appropriate armature selected and vertex weights exist on the clothes mesh for each of the necessary bones. If there aren't any weights, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719718/transferring-rig-weights-from-one-mesh-to-another-in-blender-2-76 for info on how to transfer weights form the character to the clothes.

Comment: This truly helped a lot. Thanks for the information Sazerac